# Encoding a string (in UTF-8) as binary data in JavaScript cross-browser

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, binary-data

I am developing a web page that communicates with the server via AJAX. The server is expecting **binary** data in a specific format. At the moment my JavaScript code can generate the entire data the server is expecting, except for one part which consists of a UTF-8 representation of some string parameter.

In short, what I need is a JavaScript function that gets a string `s` and returns its UTF-8 representation as a `Uint8Array`.

This is very easy in Firefox, which has the `TextEncoder` class:

```
function utf8(s) {
  return new TextEncoder().encode(s);
}
```

Unfortunately, Firefox is not the only browser out there ;-) Does anyone know of a way to do this cross-browser?

I could write up my own encoder, but I'd rather use something native if it's possible.

Note: I would gladly welcome a non-cross-browser solution as long as it works on Google Chrome.

Comment: Since you know that the solution to your problem is an UTF-8 encoder, I 'm voting to close this because it asks for a library recommendation. Google can answer it in a second.

Comment: @Jon - I'm not looking for a library. Also, Google did not answer my question (Google was my first, and second, ... and tenth attempt before coming to SO).

Comment: Well, [it answered the question for me](https://www.google.gr/#q=js+utf-8+encode).

Comment: @Jon - can you point me to a specific link? I checked a few and none of them provides what I want. (Notice I want the UTF-8-encoding in **binary**, i.e. `Uint8Array`, not as text.)

Comment: [This](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html) is a UTF-8 encoder/decoder. If you don't want the result in a string but rather in an Uint8Array then simply don't put the encoding results into a string with `String.fromCharCode` but directly write the char code into the array instead.

Comment: @Jon - thanks for your time and efforts. As I said, I could write my own encoder; I'll do it if I have to, but my question was about a native solution (e.g. if Chrome has something similar to Firefox's TextEncoder). (By the way, and this is already not really related to my original question, I had a look at the code in that link, and it doesn't make sense: why would they String.fromCharCode the binary byte codes that make the UTF-8 encoding?!)

Comment: Because you might be getting non-UTF-8 encoded content from somewhere and want to print it in a UTF-8-encoded page. Doesn't matter really. You can use a string as a binary-safe buffer anytime you want, which is why "as binary, not as text" is a trivial distinction.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) for the [Encoding Living Standard](http://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/) API, which `TextEncoder` is part of.

`TextEncoder` is shipping in Chrome 38.  See [Encoding API](http://www.chromestatus.com/features/5714368087982080) entry from Chromium Dashboard and Chromium Issue [398149](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=398149):    Text Encoding API.

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin! Not so relevant for me anymore, but I hope someone might find it useful in the future.